# Using Use Effect with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image]I am trying to create a demo weather fetching app , I need to display weather data of city name as typed , can it be achieved with us effect or there is any other approach for the same
also I need to display results only if data exits currently in my code if data is not available .. default state data is showing kindly suggest to fix both issues

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import Clock from "react-live-clock";
import "./Weather.css";

import {
  ToastContainer,
  toast
} from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import {
  API_KEY
} from "./Api";

export default function Weather() {
  const [city, setcity] = useState("goa");
  const [currentweather, setcurrentweather] = useState("");
  const [icon, seticon] = useState("");
  const [weathertext, setweathertext] = useState("")

  const lpsearch = () => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;

    if (city) {
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.cod === "404") {
            // console.log("City Not found");
            toast.error(`Entered City-Name  ${city} Not Found `, {
              position: "top-center",
              autoClose: 2000,
              hideProgressBar: false,
              closeOnClick: true,
              pauseOnHover: true,
              draggable: true,
              progress: undefined,
            });
            setcity("");
          } else {
            console.log(data);
            setcurrentweather(data.main.temp);
            setweathertext(data.weather[0].description)
            seticon(data.weather[0].icon);
            setcity("");
          }

          // setcity("");
        });
    }
  };

  let inputhndl = (event) => {
    setcity(event.target.value);
  };

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    ToastContainer position = "top-center"
    autoClose = {
      2000
    }
    hideProgressBar = {
      false
    }
    newestOnTop = {
      false
    }
    closeOnClick rtl = {
      false
    }
    pauseOnFocusLoss draggable pauseOnHover /
    > {
      " "
    } <
    div className = "container-fluid" > {
      " "
    } <
    h2 className = "text-center alert-success font-weight-bolder " >
    <
    Clock format = {
      "dddd, DD  MMMM   , YYYY, h:mm:ss"
    }
    ticking = {
      true
    }
    /> <
    /h2> <
    /div> <
    div className = "lpcentered  " >
    <
    h3 className = "alert-info text-capitalize text-center" >
    Enter City 's <i className="fas fa-city text-secondary"></i> Name <
    /h3> <
    input onChange = {
      inputhndl
    }
    value = {
      city
    }
    placeholder = "Enter Here"
    className = "form-control btn-outline-warning font-weight-bolder mb-3 mt-3" >
    < /input> <
    button className = "form-control btn-success font-weight-bold "
    onClick = {
      lpsearch
    } >
    Search < i className = "fas fa-search  " > < /i> <
    /button> <
    div className = "text-center" >
    <
    h3 className = "alert-secondary text-capitalize" > {
      city
    } < /h3>

    <
    h3 className = "text-capitalize alert-info" > {
      city
    } < i class = "fas fa-temperature-low" > < /i> - {currentweather}  <span>&#8451;</span > < /h3> <
    h3 > {
      weathertext
    } < img src = {
      `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}@2x.png`
    }
    alt = "icon"
    srcset = "" /
    > < /h3>

    <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    /div>
  );
}
```

Comment: (sorry, my edit wasn't helpful)

Comment: np thnks for checking out

Comment: What does useEffect do? By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render. React will remember the function you passed (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and call it later after performing the DOM updates. In this effect, we set the document title, but we could also perform data fetching or call some other imperative API.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: if this `hideProgressBar = {
      false
    }` is `false`, so why you added it?

Comment: You need `useEffect(() => { lpsearch(); }, [city]);`. This will call the function each time `city` changes. As for the 2nd issue, look into conditional rendering: `{ currentWeather !== "" && <div>blah</div> }`

Comment: thanks its helps but i am unable to complete  city names for example if am trying london and i typed till lod it fetches data for city lod how can i avoid it & wait for the input to be complete

Comment: I remembered the name of this concept again: *debounce*. Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-sun-gv1ys?file=/src/App.js (check the console at the bottom of the right part)